# Firebase send email function

Tags: firebase, gmail

I have been playing around with firebase tutorials and the new functions, and trying to implement this specific example:
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users

When I fire the trigger the mail does not get sent, and I get the following error in the log console:

```
Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 141sm3120746ioe.47 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:557:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1248:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:340:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:706:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:509:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/user_code/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:461:47)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
```

What am I doing wrong? It does not say anthing about placing some authorizations on email account. Just the password. Should be simple.

Comment: Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can't say much more than the error message already does: you're passing in a username/password combination that gmail can't verify.

Comment: Well, code is copy/pasted from the example.
As for the username/password this is 100% correct.

Comment: If you need help troubleshooting Firebase features, please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: you set it like this `firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="myusername@gmail.com" gmail.password="secretpassword"` ? are using 2-step verification ?

Comment: When I type in 'firebase functions:config:get' i get the set parameters, so this is ok I guess. As for the verification, the answer is no, I do not have this.

Comment: For me the issue was solved by just waiting 24 hours (on a G Suite account) after enabling "insecure access". I tried after 1 hour and it was still blocked. On a regular gmail account I also had to manually unblock the "device" at https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/device-activity. That setting propagation time can really throw one off.

Answer (score 5):

If you type: `firebase functions:config:get` in the Terminal, you would be able to see that the gmail and password is with **double quotation marks**.
Mine was like this:

```
{
  "gmail": {
    "password": ""pass"",
    "email": ""user@gmail.com""
  }
}
```

So I typed in like this in the Terminal and it worked for me:
**WITHOUT QUATATION MARKS**

```
firebase functions:config:set gmail.email=user@gmail.com gmail.password=pass
```

Answer (score 1):

not too sure if you've done the initial configuration part as listed [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/email-users/functions/index.js#L20)

`For Gmail, enable these:
1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
2. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha`

If you have already done this, you can pass the `email` and `password` as a string on `const gmailEmail = 'gmail.com'` and `const gmailPassword = 'password'` to check if it's working